# CKEditor5 with Angular 9 basic install causing "'ckeditor' is not a known element:'"

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I am following the CKEditor Angular 2.x installation instructions and after installing CKEditor to my new Angular 9 project and attempting to add the CKEditor markup to my component's HTML page my Webstorm IDE gets a compile error and says:

'ckeditor' is not a known element:'

and

Can't bind to 'editor' since it isn't a known property of 'ckeditor'.

The WYSIWYG editor does not show up. 
Here are the instructions I followed: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/11.0.1/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html
Then instructions do not say it only works with certain Angular 2.x versions.
I made sure to add CKEditorModule to my application module imports.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what I was doing wrong.
I was adding "CKEditorModule" to the exports rather than the imports of app.module.ts.

I added "CKEditorModule" to the imports of app.module.ts and now the WYSIWYG loads properly.